# Iterating object - Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have problem.

This command shows this value
[image]

And if you want to call something from the `photos` object, it gets an error.

```
console.log(data.photos.total)
UserProfilGallery.js:17 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'total' of undefined
```

Why is this happening? I can not find the cause of this error

Comment: @AndrewMyers it was an example. If he wants to call data.photos.page, data.photos.photo the situation is the same

Comment: You are probably trying to access it before API/data-source brings the result back. Try `var total = data && data.photos ? data.photos.total : 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you see an `undefined` in your console just before the data. That's because the data.photos is indeed undefined at that time. Add a check that will at least solve the error: `data.photos && data.photos.total` this way if `data.photos` has a value - it will access the `total` property.

Comment: He might not necessarily be getting an undefined if the `data` object is created first and the contents are added later. At the point the `console.log` happens, `data` will in fact be an empty object, but dev tools won't actually evaluate the object until you click the arrow to expand the contents. That's what that little blue i is talking about.

Comment: Indeed, but the check will still help.